# pgf matrix plot mask values in colormap

Tags: tikz-pgf, bibtex, plot

I would like to make a matrix plot with the following script, where all 0 values are displayed in white all other values according to the colormap. Is there a masking feature in pgf plot? Could it be done with a feature which assigns a certain color to all values below a certain value? All values I want to display according to the colorplot are larger than 0.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[view={0}{90},
enlargelimits=false,
xtick=data, ytick=data,
colorbar,
colormap/viridis
]
\addplot3[matrix plot]
table[] {
1 1 1
2 1 2
3 1 0

1 2 0
2 2 3
3 2 1 
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I have this code at the moment which outputs a result like this:
[image]